# What is the maximum physical drive size on an HP p420i RAID controller?

Tags: hp, drive, raid-controller

How big hard drives can be used with an HP p420i RAID controller?

[HP mentions that 8 TB drives can be used](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c03235277).

Comment: HP has 16 TB drives (P25247-001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive Googled a hour and wont find any info if bigger Drives will work, so i equipped a Z220 Workstation with a 1GB P420 Controller (similar to P420i, but the Card version, the i is integrated)
And attached two 20TB Seagate EXOS X20 Drives
IT WORKS!!!

Confirmed 10-02-2023

[RaidBIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESdqw.jpg)

[RaidBIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvxTB.jpg)

[RaidBIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvEpU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows how big hard drives could be used on your server, you could try disks with bigger, but it can only be determined in practice. Vendor guarantee, that system would work with 8Tb disks without any issues, all other cases yo do at one's own risk.

Comment: I don't ask about a server. I ask about a RAID controller.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a quickspec for the P420/420i that listed the 8TB disk as being supported, in fact I can only find one referring to 4TB disks but that document you link to is clear - it supports 8TB HPE disks - there's no other controller listed for that server model but the P420/420i, so it must support them! That said there's a chance the zero-memory version might not support these larger disks, quite often with this generation of controller additional memory was needed for some of the 'higher' functions such as RAID level migration, so I'd be strongly tempted to make sure I had at least some memory on my controller before adding larger disks.